# Display time left to vote again

Tags: php, mysql, date

I got a voting script that allow people to vote for an item in the database every 24 hour and some more code to check if 24 hours have past or not using `'NOW()'` and `'DATE_SUB( NOW()`, `'INTERVAL 1 DAY'`.

I'm currently trying to add the feature to display how much time is left before the user can vote again using the code below.

```
$time = explode(" ", $voteCheck[1]);
$year = explode("-", $time[0]);
$date = explode(":", $time[1]);

// Set it all to one long string
$time = $year[0].$year[1].$year[2].$date[0].$date[1].$date[2];

// Current time and date
$cTime = date("YmdHis");

// I get lost here
```

votcheck is an array from a sql string which just returns the first row as 0 or 1.
1 if the user already voted and 0 if the user can vote again.
The second row returns the date and time the user voted.
I just can't seem to figure out what to do to get the x amount of hours left before the user can vote again.

My main problem is that the length of the $time string sometime is 13 and sometime 14 characters long.

Comment: could you please var_dump the $time variable and post the result here?

Comment: Sure, here you go.
string '20121118114800' (length=14)
I do have the problem with it returning 13 characters though, depending on the time it got set.

Comment: I actually meant `$time` before you explode it the first time

Comment: Oh, thats '2012-11-18 11:48:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here it is

```
$voted = new DateTime($time);
$daylater = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $voted->format('U')));
$canvote = new DateTime($daylater);
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$diff = $canvote->format('U') - $now->format('U'); 

if ( $diff > 0 && $diff < 86400 ) {
    $left = gmdate("H:i:s", $diff);
    echo $left . ' left till you can vote again';
} else {
    echo 'You can vote again' ;
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: N.B.: the function `gmdate` only works as long as the second argument is less than 86,400 (i.e. 24 hours) but since you are only checking for that range it works

Comment: I did try and run it but when I do the voted and now variables just return this:

object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2012-11-19 11:41:03' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

And the '$diff = $now->format('U') - $time->format('U');' line wont execute.

Comment: Why do you return a var_dump? And for the line not executing, I had a small typo in the code, sorry my bad, try again

Comment: ps. It return the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\vote.php

Comment: are you sure that '$time' is a string? Copy paste my code again I have edited it

Comment: I'm sure. Its a string both before and after the explode and the new time without all the separating is made.
I did try to run your code but it looks like its always returns the 'You can vote again' message.

Comment: Ok I tested it myself with `$time = '2012-11-18 11:48:00';` and it works. Just forget about all your explodes, take `$time` as you get it from the database and run my code and it must absolutely work. Else contact me at bashuber (at) hotmail.com  We can not 'chat'here

Comment: I already tried that but let me get another go at it.
I'll let you know on here if it works and if it doesn't i'll be sure to send you a mail.
Thank you for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to use `strtotime()` to convert `$voteCheck[1]` directly?  You can then check the unix time stamp against the current time stamp.